# Twitter複数画像アップロード時に、画像数が1～4枚で変動する場合の動的対応

Tags: php, twitter

**環境**
TwitterOAuthライブラリ使用

---

**画像数が2で固定の場合**

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
$m1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/1.jpg']);
$m2 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/2.jpg']);
$parameters = [
  'status' => '文字列',
  'media_ids' => implode(',', [
    $m1->media_id_string,
    $m2->media_id_string
  ])
];
```

---

**画像数が1～4で変動する場合**
最初に考えた疑似コード

```
if(画像数が1枚){
  $m1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/1.jpg']);
  $parameters = [
    'status' => '文字列',
    'media_ids' => implode(',', [
      $m1->media_id_string
    ])
  ];
}elseif(画像数が2枚){
  $m1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/1.jpg']);
  $m2 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/2.jpg']);
  $parameters = [
    'status' => '文字列',
    'media_ids' => implode(',', [
      $m1->media_id_string,
      $m2->media_id_string
    ])
  ];
}elseif(画像数が3枚){

}elseif(画像数が4枚){

}
```

もう少しスマートに書くには？

Comment: 繰り返しの処理は `for` や `while` を使うのが定石かと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スマートという定義がいまいち曖昧ですが、
・繰り返し処理にはfor文を使う
ということであれば

```
$image_num = 画像数;
$image_media_ids = [];
for ($i = 1; $i++; $i <= $image_num) {
    $m = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => './img/{$i}.jpg']);
    $image_media_ids[] = $m->media_id_string;
}

$parameters = [
  'status' => '文字列',
  'media_ids' => implode(',', $image_media_ids)
];
```

これがシンプルで見やすいコードでしょうか？